# How to programatically move a QDockWidget from one dock area to another?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt4

How can I programmatically move a `QDockWidget` from `Qt.DockWidgetArea.TopDockWidgetArea` to `Qt.DockWidgetArea.RightDockWidgetArea` using pyqt?

`Qt.DockWidgetArea.RightDockWidgetArea` might contain no existing widgets, so using `QMainWindow.splitDockWidget()` doesn't seem to be an option as that requires an existing widget from the target dock area.

Comment: Just call `addDockWidget()` again with the other area instead.

Comment: Note that QDockWidget lay-out isn't really designed or intended to be fully programmatically configurable. Prepare to be frustrated if you want that.

Comment: @musicamante Perfect -- works. WIll accept if u post as answer